# Continue to run next steps after Element Not displayed Exception in Selenium Java using TestNG framework

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

I have a code to check one element is displayed or not. If it's displayed it should write as 'Pass' and if element not exists, test should write as "Fail" and should continue to next steps. I have added Try catch block too, but still if element is not exists script stopped at there itself.

Here is my code:

```
//Click Bautowatch
        WebElement bautoWatch = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Bautowatch')]"));
        bautoWatch.click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        //Click Bautowatch Process
        WebElement bautoProcess = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Process')]"));
        bautoProcess.click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

       //Check Process header is displayed to confirm Bautowatch Process page is loaded
            try {
                WebElement processHeader = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[contains(text(),'Processnew')])[1]"));
                assert processHeader.isDisplayed();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Bautowatch Process - Pass");
                Properties.screenshotMethod(driver, "Bautowatch Process - Pass");
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                System.out.println("Bautowatch Process - Fail");
                Properties.screenshotMethod(driver, "Bautowatch Process - Fail");
            }

       //Click Bautowatch Connector
        WebElement bautoConnector = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[contains(text(),'Connector')])[1]"));
        bautoConnector.click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        //Check Connector header is displayed to confirm Bautowatch Connector page is loaded
        WebElement connectorHeader = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[contains(text(),'Connector')])[1]"));
        try {
            assert connectorHeader.isDisplayed();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Bautowatch Connector - Pass");
            Properties.screenshotMethod(driver,"Bautowatch Connector - Pass");
        }catch (AssertionError e){
            System.out.println("Bautowatch Connector - Fail");
            Properties.screenshotMethod(driver,"Bautowatch Connector - Fail");
        }
```

My script should mark as fail and keep run next steps if any element not exists

Answer (score 1):

Use `findElements` instead of `findElement`.

`findElements` will handle `NoSuchElementException` better than the former.

> findElement - Throws NoSuchElementException if the element is not found, and aborts the execution

> findElements - Returns an empty list if no matching element is found and continues to the next line of code

See the example code below:

```
List<WebElement> processHeader = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//div[contains(text(),'Processnew')])[1]"));
if (processHeader.size() >= 1) {
    System.out.println("Pass");
} else {
    System.out.println("Fail");
}
```

#### UPDATE:

`java.lang.AssertionError` this happens when an Assertion (the thing you're trying to verify) fails. When you get an AssertionError, it doesn't mean that your code fails, but it means that the condition you were checking wasn't true. If you want to assert something and when the assertion fails, if you want to continue with your script execution, then you need to use [Soft Assert](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hard-assert-vs-soft-assert/).

Change the below code:

```
assert processHeader.size() >= 1;
```

To:

```
Assertion softAssert = new SoftAssert();
softAssert.assertTrue(processHeader.size() >= 1);
```

Imports required:

```
import org.testng.asserts.Assertion;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;
```

Comment: Thanks @shawn but still facing the same. Script stopped at assertion and not proceeding further

Comment: Can you share the modified code in the question? Also, when you say 'script stopped', what exception do you see on the console?

Comment: try {

            List <WebElement> processHeader =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//div[contains(text(),'Processnew')])[1]"));
            assert processHeader.size() >=1;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Bautowatch Process - Pass");
            Properties.screenshotMethod(driver, "Bautowatch Process - Pass");
        } catch (NoSuchElementException | IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Bautowatch Process - Fail");
            Properties.screenshotMethod(driver, "Bautowatch Process - Fail");
        }

Comment: above is the edited code and facing below error

java.lang.AssertionError